# Stop EditorFor<> from adding a 0 to int properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, default-value

I have a View-model with a few properties that are `int` and when I use an `@Html.EditorFor` in the View a text box is generated but it fills it with the number **0**. *I don't want the text box to be prefilled with anything*, how can I stop this **without making the property nullable?**

ViewModel:

```
public class TransactionVM
{
    [DisplayName("Ticket #"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public int TicketNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Customers { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Carrier")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Carriers { get; set; }
    public int CarrierId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Driver")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Drivers { get; set; }
    public int DriverID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gross Gallons\n(Max: 6,000)")]
    public decimal GrossGallons { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Net Gallons")]
    public decimal NetGallons { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Sale Start Number")]
    public string SaleStartNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Transaction Date and Time")]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        TransactionVM model = new TransactionVM();
        return View(model);

        using (var db = new DynamicDbContext())
        {
            model.Customers = new SelectList(db.GetList<Customer>(c => c.Id > 0).ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TicketNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TicketNumber)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This is not about disabling model binding. I want to place data in the view to populate the dropdowns and also need all the data bound to it on post to manipulate it in the controller.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi I  want to keep model binding so I can both pass up data for the select lists as well as be able to simply take the submitted data, bind it to the VM and then work with that data. This is not a model binding issue.

Comment: Making the property nullable is the correct way of doing it.. What is stopping you from doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure and didn't try it but you can try to set `value` property like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TicketNumber, new { @value = "" })
```

Edit: another way would be using `jQuery`:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#TicketNumber").val("");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Selman22 I just tried this on the TicketNumber property and it still had a 0 in the text box.

Comment: Just tried `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TicketNumber, new { value = "test" })` and the value was still 0, even tryied `@value` with no luck.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete then jQuery is your friend :) if you really want to remove the `0`. try the second solution.

Comment: @Selman22 I was really hoping to not have to use jQuery, while this VM only has 3 instances of this problem there will be much much bigger VMs that will have a heck of a lot more and that much JavaScript will be both annoying to code out AND bog down the uers (some of there machines are still on Win 95 and there is nothing I can do about that).

Comment: Marked this as answer for the jQuery solution.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete I understand your problem sorry I couldn't give you a feedback.but there is nothing I can do since you don't want to make your properties nullable.Another way would be using a custom html helper method ? and configure it however you like.if you really cannot use jQuery then you can try that way.

Comment: @Value  actually

Answer (score 0):

Add `[DefaultValue(null)]` DataAnnotaion to your model properties. Or at least set default  values in controller action (one that uses `[HttpGet]`) to prepare page! Or remove value property via jQuery in client side.

Comment: The value of 0 is still presented in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to setting the model property to Nullable is editing the ModelState directly.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new TransactionVM();
  ModelState.SetModelValue("TicketNumber", new ValueProviderResult("", "", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
  return model;
}
```

You have to be careful to do this in the POST action as well, and then only in cases where the value is `0`.